# how to auto login with kakao, google, naver id in certain web site using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to make selenium login code of this website. the selenium login keys get's error.

https://member.jinhak.com/MemberV3/MemberJoin/MemberLogIn.aspx?ReturnSite=JM&ReturnURL=http%3a%2f%2fwww.jinhak.com%2findex.aspx
[image]

if I click each button. they show the login tab.

for example, when I click the naver login button and get xpath from devtools. but while executing the code print's this error for all kinds of the login tabs

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
[@id="id"]

I would like to know why they aren't working.

```
   nick = input('id : ').strip()
    pwd = input('password ').strip()
    nick_type = (input('id type [default : None naver : 1 kakao : 2 google : 3] : ') or None)
    # fname = (input('path to existing excel file(test.xlsx) : ') or './test.xlsx').strip()


    options = Options()
    # options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("https://www.jinhak.com/")

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="util"]/div/ul/li[1]/a').click()

    if nick_type:
        try: 
            if nick_type == 'naver' or nick_type == '1':
                driver.find_element(By.ID,'naverIdLogin_loginButton').click()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                #login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="frmNIDLogin"]/ul/li/div/div[2]').send_keys(nick)
                login.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id"]').send_keys(nick)
                login.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pw"]').send_keys(pwd)
                driver.find_element(By.ID,'log.login').click()
            elif nick_type == 'kakao' or nick_type == '2':
                driver.find_element(By.ID,'btnLoginK').click()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  
                id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_email_2_label"]/span[1]').click()
                id.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_email_2"]').send_keys(nick)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginEmailField"]/p').click()
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_password_3"]').click().send_keys(pwd)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login-form"]/fieldset/div[8]/button[1]').click()
            elif nick_type == 'google' or nick_type == '3':
                driver.find_element(By.ID,'btnLoginG').click()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierId"]').click()
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierId"]').click().send_keys(nick)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/span').click()
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(pwd)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/span').click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="txtMemID"]').send_keys(nick)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="txtMemPass"]').send_keys(pwd)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="panel_1"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/button').click()
```

Comment: Is naver the green N. Also can you show your attempt.

Comment: yes naver is green and kakao is yellow

Comment: I can't see `//*[@id="id_line"]` in your code. On what step of your code the error appears? What happens when you insert the username and password and clicking the login button?

Comment: the inserting id doesn't work..

Comment: I've changed it to [@id="id"]

Comment: Ok will write an answer.

Comment: @user1173330 Check out my answer to clarify what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)                                 

driver.get('https://www.jinhak.com/')

nick=1
us='1'
pw='1'
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="util"]/div/ul/li[1]/a').click()
try:
    if nick==1:
        driver.find_element(By.ID,'naverIdLogin_loginButton').click()
        wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        driver.find_element(By.ID,'id').send_keys(us)        
        driver.find_element(By.ID,'pw').send_keys(pw)
        driver.find_element(By.ID,'log\.login').click()  
    elif nick==2:
        pass
    elif nick==3:
        pass
    else:
        pass
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    pass
```

The main issue for that was the handling of driver handles, closing and then switching to different windows. You should use webdriver waits to make sure your windows are opened as well.

Another thing you can do that will make your testing more secure is to use waits for elements to pop up.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"something")))
```

Finally what would happened if you tried clicking on the values in your except and they failed it's better to put it all in the try and then catch the exceptions.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: typing id and password absolutely workssss!! but in my case there pops security authentication for checking human..ㅠㅠ